# Getting a Select tag created for each option, instead of one for all options

Tags: php, mysql

My `select` that fetch all the data show all of then in separate drop downs

**Question:** how do i get all my vales in the same drop down?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "categorys";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM all_category";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
        echo "<select>";
        echo '<option>' . $row['category'] . '</option>';
        echo "</select>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your select tag out of the loop and use only the option tag:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<select>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
        echo '<option>' . $row['category'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Also, indenting the code will make it look nicer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are opening and closing new `<select>` tags in a while loop. This needs to be done outside the loop itself:

```
echo "<select>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo '<option>' . $row['category'] . '</option>';   
}
echo "</select>";
```